# How to control bandwidth in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, bandwidth, throttling

I share my internet connection, which is very slow, with two friends. When one of us tries to watch a video or download something, he usually "eats up" all the bandwidth. All of us use Firefox and want to control the bandwidth only for this browser.

The problem is that we use both Linux and Windows, and changing an OS is not an option. Is there either a solution that works for both operation systems, or separate solutions for each OS?

I've seen something called throttle but it works only with old releases of Firefox. is there any other option to do this?

Configuring QoS is not an option since the modem doesn't give that option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Linux, you could use [`trickle`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/trickle), which works for any application.

For example, running

```
$ trickle -d 50 -u 10 firefox
```

in the terminal will start Firefox and limit it to 50 kB/s download and 10 kB/s upload. *For Firefox, make sure no other instance is running.*

On Windows, you might give give a [shot](https://www.google.nl/search?q=bandwith%20limiting%20application%20windows) on Google. My first hit was [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/), non-free, unfortunately.

For a more reliable and network-wide and cross-platform solution I recommend looking at configuring QoS on your router.

Comment: Is this for windows or linux??

Comment: It is for linux.

Comment: @poz2k4444 Unfortunately it seems to be available for Linux only. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: The problem here is we use both, linux and windows OS, I can use this solution but they never wanted to change their OS, is there any solution on windows?? (I edit my question)

Comment: @poz2k4444 Configuring QoS properly will work for windows, mac, and linux.

Comment: But configurin QoS affect the entire host or just some specific application??

Comment: @poz2k4444 QoS will prioritize traffic based on port number, TCP flags, source/destiation IP addres, etc. It cannot guess what application is generating the traffic, no. But it can help you to shape the small bandwith to be usable for others when some user is trying to use all the bandwith available.

Comment: @gertvdijk well, I've checked my modem and it cannot configure QoS, is there any other option?

Comment: @poz2k4444 Is your modem also your router? QoS is usually configured on routers, not modems. I don't know about bandwidth limiting software on Windows, but back in the old days I've used [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/) (non-free).

Comment: @gertvdijk Yes, the modem is also my router and provide wireless connection, this is not a professional network, it's for our personal use in our home, is there something free?? I've seen around the web and cannot find something useful...

Comment: @gertvdijk I used trickle, one question, when I close the app that launch with trickle, it stops managing the bandwidth?

Comment: @poz2k4444 Invoking a command with ``trickle`` just manages the bandwidth until the process ends. However, you could set up ``trickled`` (daemon) to manage bandwidth of applications continuously. See ``man trickled.conf`` on how to configure that.

Comment: @gertvdijk I'll check it later, thanks for the tip, but still there is something that could do something similar in windows??

Answer (score 0):

If useful, I'm doing it on Windows using an old version* of NetBalancer (v3.1.1). This allow you to limit the download and upload bandwith of every process, and remembers the values. Note that you will need admin privileges because it is installed as a controller and add a service.

(*) The last version, v9.4.1, has this feature only during the trial period.